# How do I strip bad chars from a string in JS?

Tags: javascript, json, string, sanitization

My JS saves some string data to JSON using "stringify()", but observing the outputted JSON string I see a lot of strange chars (out of keyspace), such as NULLs and other bad chars. Now I don't have a list of these "bad" chars so how can I strip them out of my string data?

Comment: What causes those strange characters? It would be better to investigate the root cause and fix it there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be nice if there was a simple RegEx for that, but I don't think there is.  From what I understand, you still want to allow characters like %$#@, etc, but want to disallow other oddball chars like tabs and nulls.  If this is correct, I believe the easiest way would be to loop each character and evaluate the char code...

```
function stripCrap(val) {
  var result = '';

  for(var i = 0, l = val.length; i < l; i++) {
    var s = val[i];
    if(String.toCharCode(s) > 31)
      result += s;
  }

  return result;
}
```

If you really want to use RegEx, a whitelist approach seems necessary.  This will allow all numbers, letters, and a space...

```
val = val.replace(/[^a-z 0-9]+/gi,'');
```

Comment: thanks so much for the whitelist suggestion. Such a great solution fro this problem

Comment: I'm getting the error: `TypeError: Object function String() { [native code] } has no method 'toCharCode'` in chrome

Comment: I got it working, just change that line to: `if (s.charCodeAt(0) > 31) {`

Comment: It's potentially going to be a pretty long list to get a reasonable character set (including standard punctuation), but if you don't care about Unicode this can be a good last resort where other cleaning methods fail.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of the "good" chars you could create a regex which matches any character *not* in your list, and strip anything it matches - for instance, the following regex matches anything *not* the letters "a", "q", or "z":

```
/[^aqz]+/ig
```